# How to pull selected date value from jsCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-range

I really like this calendar plugin for my mobile site: https://github.com/michaelkamphausen/jsCalendar

Seen working here: http://jsfiddle.net/dQxVV/1/

I am pretty new at JS and am having trouble figuring out

1. How to collect the selected start and end dates (place them into an input value)
2. How to show more than one month.

I really appreciate any help on this or if you have a suggestion for a better mobile friendly calendar.

JS building date range calendar:

```
$(".jsCalendar").bind("startDateChanged", function () {
$(this).data("startdate");
}).bind("endDateChanged", function () {
$(this).data("enddate");
});
```

calendar.js

```
(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $calendars = $(".jsCalendar");
    for (var i = 0, maxI = $calendars.length; i < maxI; i++) {
        var calendar = new Calendar();
        calendar.ready($calendars.eq(i));
    }
});

function Calendar() {
    var self = this,
    $calendar,
    $previous,
    $next,
    $month,
    $weekdays,
    $days,
    $rows,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    currentMonth,
    today,
    minDate,
    dateInfo,
    singleDate,
    firstDayOfWeek = 0,
    tap = 'click',
    noAnimEnd = "noAnimationEnd",

    startDateString = "startDate",
    endDateString = "endDate",

    setDate = function (type, value) {
        value && value.clearTime && value.clearTime();
        if (type == startDateString) {
            startDate = value;
        } else {
            endDate = value;
        }
        drawSelection();
        $calendar.data(type.toLowerCase(), !value ? "" : value.toString());
        $calendar.trigger(type + "Changed");
    },

    dateSelected = function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass("inactive") || ($this.text().length == 0)) {
            return;
        }
        var selectedDate = new Date(currentMonth.getFullYear(), currentMonth.getMonth(), parseInt($this.text()));
        if (singleDate) {
            setDate(startDateString, !startDate || (selectedDate.getTime() != startDate.getTime()) ? selectedDate : null);
            return;
        }
        if (!startDate) {
            if (!endDate) {
                setDate(startDateString, selectedDate);
            } else {
                if (selectedDate < endDate) {
                    setDate(startDateString, selectedDate);
                } else if (endDate < selectedDate) {
                    setDate(startDateString, endDate);
                    setDate(endDateString, selectedDate);
                } else {
                    setDate(endDateString, null);
                }
            }
        } else if (!endDate) {
            if (startDate < selectedDate) {
                setDate(endDateString, selectedDate);
            } else if (selectedDate < startDate) {
                setDate(endDateString, startDate);
                setDate(startDateString, selectedDate);
            } else {
                setDate(startDateString, null);
            }
        } else {
            if ($this.hasClass(startDateString)) {
                setDate(startDateString, null);
            } else if ($this.hasClass(endDateString)) {
                setDate(endDateString, null);
            } else {
                setDate(startDateString, null);
                setDate(endDateString, null);
            }
        }
    },

    extendDate = function () {
        /* subset from date.js, http://www.datejs.com/ */
        Date.prototype.clone=function(){return new Date(this.getTime());}
        Date.prototype.isLeapYear=function(){var y=this.getFullYear();return(((y%4===0)&&(y%100!==0))||(y%400===0));}
        Date.prototype.getDaysInMonth=function(){return [31,(this.isLeapYear(this.getFullYear())?29:28),31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][this.getMonth()];}
        Date.prototype.moveToFirstDayOfMonth=function(){this.setDate(1);return this;}
        Date.prototype.moveToLastDayOfMonth=function(){this.setDate(this.getDaysInMonth());return this;}
        Date.prototype.addMilliseconds=function(value){this.setMilliseconds(this.getMilliseconds()+value);return this;}
        Date.prototype.addDays=function(value){return this.addMilliseconds(value*86400000);}
        Date.prototype.addMonths=function(value){var n=this.getDate();this.setDate(1);this.setMonth(this.getMonth()+value);this.setDate(Math.min(n,this.getDaysInMonth()));return this;}
        Date.prototype.clearTime=function(){this.setHours(0);this.setMinutes(0);this.setSeconds(0);this.setMilliseconds(0);return this;}
    },

    getDay = function (day) {
        return (day + firstDayOfWeek) % 7; // changing first day of week
    },

    drawSelection = function () {
        $days.removeClass(startDateString).removeClass(endDateString).removeClass("betweenDates");
        var firstDay = currentMonth.clone().moveToFirstDayOfMonth();
        var lastDay = currentMonth.clone().moveToLastDayOfMonth();
        var dayOffset = getDay(firstDay.getDay()) - 1;

        if (!!startDate && !!endDate && (startDate < lastDay) && (endDate > firstDay)) {
            var firstBetweenDay = new Date(Math.max(firstDay, startDate.clone().addDays(1)));
            var lastBetweenDay = new Date(Math.min(lastDay, endDate.clone().addDays(-1)));
            if (firstBetweenDay <= lastBetweenDay) {
                $days.slice(dayOffset + firstBetweenDay.getDate(), dayOffset + lastBetweenDay.getDate() + 1).addClass("betweenDates");
            }
        }
        if (!!startDate && (firstDay <= startDate) && (startDate <= lastDay)) {
            $days.eq(dayOffset + startDate.getDate()).addClass(startDateString);
        }
        if (!!endDate && (firstDay <= endDate) && (endDate <= lastDay)) {
            $days.eq(dayOffset + endDate.getDate()).addClass(endDateString);
        }
    };

    self.ready = function ($element) {
        $calendar = $element;
        $previous = $('<a href="#">&lt;</a>');
        $next = $('<a href="#">&gt;</a>');
        $month = $('<li class="calMonth"></li>');
        $calendar.append($('<ul class="calButtonBar"></ul>')
            .append($('<li class="calPrevious"></li>').append($previous))
            .append($month)
            .append($('<li class="calNext"></li>').append($next))
        );
        for (var i = 0, th = "", td = ""; i < 7; i++) {
          th += '<th></th>';
          td += '<td><a href="#"></a></td>';
        }
        for (var i = 0, tr = ""; i < 6; i++) {
          tr += '<tr>' + td + '</tr>';
        }
        $calendar.append('<div class="calGrid"><table><tr>' + th + '</tr>' + tr + '</table></div>');
        $weekdays = $calendar.find("th");
        $days = $calendar.find("td a");
        $rows = $calendar.find("tr");
        $rows.eq(1).addClass("first");

        singleDate = $calendar.hasClass("jsSingleDate");
        firstDayOfWeek = $calendar.data("firstdayofweek") || firstDayOfWeek;

        $calendar.get(0).calendar = self;
        if ($.fn) {
            $.fn.slice = $.fn.slice || function (start, end) {
                return $([].slice.call(this, start, end));
            }
            $.fn.calendar = function() {
                return this.get(0).calendar;
            }
        }

        extendDate();
        today = (new Date()).clearTime();
        minDate = today;
        startDate = $calendar.data("startdate");
        startDate = startDate ? new Date(startDate).clearTime() : null;
        endDate = $calendar.data("enddate");
        endDate = endDate ? new Date(endDate).clearTime() : null;
        currentMonth = (startDate || today).clone();

        dateInfo = $calendar.data("localized_date");
        if (typeof dateInfo == "string") {
            dateInfo = JSON.parse(dateInfo);
        }

        var $monthGrid = $calendar.find(".calGrid");
        var animationQueue = [];
        var isAnimating = function(node) {
            if ($monthGrid.children().length > 1) {
                animationQueue.push(node);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        var nextAnimation = function() {
            if (animationQueue.length > 0) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  animationQueue.shift().trigger(tap);
                }, 0);
            }
        }
        $previous.bind(tap, function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            if (isAnimating($previous)) return;
            currentMonth = currentMonth.addMonths(-1);
            var $page = $('<table>' + $calendar.find("table").html() + '</table>');
            $monthGrid.append($page);
            $days.closest("table").addClass("turndown").bind(animEnd, function (evt) {
                $(this).removeClass("turndown").unbind(animEnd);
                $page.remove();
                nextAnimation();
            }).trigger(noAnimEnd);
            self.showMonth(currentMonth);
        });
        $next.bind(tap, function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            if (isAnimating($next)) return;
            currentMonth = currentMonth.addMonths(+1);
            var $page = $('<table class="turnup">' + $calendar.find("table").html() + '</table>');
            $monthGrid.append($page);
            $page.bind(animEnd, function (evt) {
                $page.remove();
                nextAnimation();
            }).trigger(noAnimEnd);
            self.showMonth(currentMonth);
        });

        $calendar.bind("resetDates", function (evt) {
            setDate(startDateString, null);
            setDate(endDateString, null);
        });

        $days.bind(tap, dateSelected);

        self.showMonth(currentMonth);
    }

    self.setDates = function(start, end) {
        setDate(startDateString, start && end ? new Date(Math.min(start, end)) : start);
        !singleDate && setDate(endDateString, start && end ? 
            (start.getTime() != end.getTime() ? new Date(Math.max(start, end)) : null) : end);
    }

    self.showMonth = function (date) {
        minDate = new Date(Math.max(minDate, today));

        if (!!dateInfo) {
            $month.text(dateInfo.months.names["long"][date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear());
            for (var i = 0, maxI = $weekdays.length; i < maxI; i++) {
                $weekdays.eq(getDay(i)).text(dateInfo.days.names.min[i]);
            }
        }

        var beforeMinDate = minDate > date.clone().moveToLastDayOfMonth();
        var includesToday = !beforeMinDate && (minDate >= date.clone().moveToFirstDayOfMonth());
        var minDay = minDate.getDate();

        $days.addClass("noTransition").removeClass("inactive");
        $rows.removeClass("last").removeClass("hidden");
        for (var firstDay = getDay(date.clone().moveToFirstDayOfMonth().getDay()) - 1, lastDay = firstDay + date.clone().moveToLastDayOfMonth().getDate(), i = 0, maxI = $days.length; i < maxI; i++) {
            var isDay = (i > firstDay) && (i <= lastDay);
            var $day = $days.eq(i).text(isDay ? ("" + (i - firstDay)) : "");
            if (isDay && (beforeMinDate || (includesToday && (i - firstDay < minDay)))) {
                $day.addClass("inactive");
            }
            if (includesToday && today.getDate() == (i - firstDay)) {
                $day.addClass("today");
            }
            if (i == lastDay) {
                $day.closest("tr").addClass("last").next().addClass("hidden").next().addClass("hidden");
            }
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            $days.removeClass("noTransition");
        }, 0);
        drawSelection();
    }
}
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted turns any div with a `class` of `jsCalendar` into a jsCalendar.

You're going to want to assign an individual `id` to any jsCalendar object you want to access the dates of.

You should be able to see what 2 dates the user has selected by calling the data function on the jsCalendar object.  For instance, if you had a jsCalendar with an id of `jsCalendar1`:

```
var startDate = $("#jsCalendar1").data("startdate");
var endDate = $("#jsCalendar1").data("enddate");
alert("Calendar 1 has a start date of " + startDate + " and an end date of " + endDate + ".");
```

Make sure you put this code somewhere appropriate, such as in a function that isn't called until after a user has selected a start and end date.

Here's a [working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wp7FS/)

Comment: Thanks for you help. If I put that in (with my classes) I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" in the console.

Comment: There was a syntax error - give it another shot with the updated code above.  Also, please post your entire .js file or the entire <script> section of your html.

Comment: @mcestone Also, make sure you are assigning an individual `id` as I stated above.

Comment: Thanks Leng, I updated the broken fiddle above. The JS generated an alert but both dates said "undefined"

Comment: @mcestone That's because you have to make sure you put this code somewhere appropriate, such as in a function that isn't called until after a user has selected a start and end date.

Comment: Leng thanks for all of your help, works perfectly. Do you think I would be able to format the date differently with this plugin or is that not possible?

Comment: @mcestone You're very welcome.  Yes, you can format the date however you'd like it using javascript's `Date()` function.  There's an excellent StackOverflow question on its usage [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript).  There may also be a way of changing the format jsCalendar returns, but I'm not familiar with jsCalendar.